# Relation between formulating the KKT conditions via gradients vs subdifferentials

Tags: optimization, definition, convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

> In this link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf you can find this:

[image]

> And in the Nonlinear programming book by Bazaraa page 207 you can find this:

[image]

**My question is**

Are those conditions equivalent?

Why?

What are other varieties of KKT conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if the convex functions $f, h_i$ (for $i = 1,\ldots,m$) and $\ell_j$ (for $j = 1,\ldots, r$) are differentiable, then $\partial f(x) = \{ \nabla f(x) \}$, and similarly for $h_i$ and $\ell_j$, so the condition
$$
0 \in \partial f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \partial h_i(x) + \sum_{j=1}^r v_j \partial \ell_j(x)
$$
reduces to
$$
0 = \nabla f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \nabla h_i(x) + \sum_{j=1}^r v_j \nabla \ell_j(x).
$$

The first version of the KKT conditions is very nice because it does not require the functions $f, h_i$, and $\ell_j$ to be differentiable. However, the first version is only useful (I believe) in the case where these functions are convex. (For a convex function $f$, the subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ is often a useful substitute for $\nabla f(x)$.)

On the other hand, the second version of the KKT conditions requires these functions to be differentiable, but it is useful even in cases where these functions are  nonconvex.

Comment: A big difference that I notice is the feasible point $\overline x$ mentioned in the second version and not if the first version of the KKT conditions. Could we say that $0 = \nabla f(\overline x) + \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \nabla h_i(\overline x) + \sum_{j=1}^r v_j \nabla \ell_j(\overline x)\iff 0 \in \partial f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m u_i \partial h_i(x) + \sum_{j=1}^r v_j \partial \ell_j(x)$

Comment: Or why the fesible point $\overline x$ is not mentioned in the first version?

Comment: I think that $x$ vs. $\bar{x}$ is just a different choice of notation. The first version of the KKT conditions explicitly states that $h_i(x) \leq 0$ and $\ell_i(x) = 0$, which is just an explicit way to say that $x$ is feasible.

Comment: hmm I think both explicitly states the constraints conditions $h_i(x)\le0,\ell_i(x)=0$ and $g_i(x)\le0,h_i(x)=0$, but only second version of KKT conditions mention _feasibility_ of point $\overline x.$

Comment: @user441848 I think that's because Theorem 4.3.8 was written or edited by someone in the department of redundancy department.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone hahaha you funny, seriously?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone seems like you're an expert on this things:) (saw your pp) would you mind to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828009/minimize-ctx-subject-to-ax-b-x-ge0-dual-problem I have problems with the sequence that makes $L\to-\infty $