# Optimal solution when the region is not convex

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider the problem $$\min x^2+x+y+\cdots$$ $$s.t.\ x+y = 0$$ $$x^2-4=0$$

Write the KKT conditions and find the optimal solution.

**Attempt**

Suppose I did write the KKT conditions.

For the optimal solution, I draw the region and I observed that it's not convex, it's a big N. So I cannot apply the following result.

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ convex and differentiable. Consider the problem to minimize $f(x)$ subject to $x\in X.$ And let X the a convex region, $\overline x\in X$ feasible. Then $\overline x$ is optimal solution if and only if $\nabla f(\overline x)^t(x-\overline x)\ge0$

My question is what can I do in this case?

Thanks for your help

---

*Note:*

This was an exam question, and I don't exactly recall the objective function nor if it had this conditions $x,y\ge0$ :( but clearly remember that the region was the N

Comment: I checked again and I think I wrote wrong the region, the constraints does not determine the N, but the original region had an N form so it should be = instead of $\le$, sorry.

Comment: What comes after “...” !?

Comment: Also as written there is literally two points in your feasible set - why not just evaluate the objective function at those two points?

Comment: @PrinceM I don't know what comes after "..." I don't remember. You are so right why didn't I though about it before.

Comment: @PrinceM what would happen in the case where there are more than two points?, let's suppose a small no convex region.

Comment: Well in this case since your objective function only has two variables you could try to use your constraints to get x in terms of y and then substitute into the objective and use normal old calculus.

Comment: @PrinceM right, thank you!

Comment: With more variables / less trivial situations you can use more advanced techniques like KKT and convex optimization theorems. KKT has special cases for convex problems

Comment: You dont have KKT for free,  under some regularity conditions KKT is granted like slater condition

Comment: @Redshoes yep I know, I didn't want to get deeper on it because I already asked a question that treats KKT conditions specifically here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837202/confusion-about-definition-of-kkt-conditions